# A left $K$-module is topologically free if and only if it is separated complete and torsion free.

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, modules

Following Christian Kassel's "Quantum Groups", page 390.

Prop: Let $K= \mathbb{C}[[h]]$, the algebra of formal power series in one indeterminant over the complex numbers. A left $K$-module is topologically free if and only if it is separated complete and torision free.

$(\rightarrow$) is trivial

Proof of $(\leftarrow$): Let $M$ be a separated, complete, and torsion-free module. We have to show that $M$ is of the form $V[[h]]$ for some complex vector space $V$. **Choose a vector subspace of $M$ which is suplementary to $hM$. Because of the torision-free assumption, we get $h^nM = h^nV \oplus h^{n+1}M$ for all $n \geq 0$**.

Hence: $$ \frac{M}{h^nM}=V \oplus hV \oplus \cdots \oplus h^{n-1}V = \frac{V[[h]]}{h^nV[[h]]}$$

Taking inverse limits and using the fact that $M$ and $V[[h]]$ are separated and complete, we get

$$M \cong V[[h]]$$

---

Can somebody explain the bold part to me? Thanks!

Comment: The term is *indeterminate*, not "indeterminant".  And when you write "supplementary" you mean "complementary". In a direct sum decomposition such as $V \oplus hM$, $V$ is called a complement to $hM$, not a supplement.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm looking at Kassel's text right now and he does indeed say "supplementary".... I'll check the errata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. View $M$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ and $hM$ as its subspace. Then there is a subspace $V \subseteq M$ such that $M = V \oplus hM$ (direct sum of $\mathbb{C}$-vector spaces).
2. The mapping $\varphi \colon M \longrightarrow M$, given by $\varphi(m) = hm$, is a linear transformation, because $M$ is a $K$-module. Applying it $n$ times to the decomposition above we get $h^n M = h^n V \oplus h^{n+1} M$. This allows us to write

$$ M/hM = V \oplus hV \oplus \dots \oplus h^{n-1}V \ \ \text{(again as $\mathbb{C}$-vector spaces)}.$$

3. I think the only place where we use torsion freeness of $M$ is in the following identification

$$ V \oplus hV \oplus \dots \oplus h^{n-1}V \cong V[[h]]/h^nV[[h]] $$

because we want $V \cong h^n V$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}_+$.

4. Viewing $M/hM \cong V[[h]]/h^nV[[h]]$ again as $K$-modules and taking completions we get the desired topological freeness.